# Find a window from AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue with its windowNumber to change its position

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, accessibility-api, window-position

I want to move a window with the Accessibility API.

With the following snippet

```
let options = CGWindowListOption(arrayLiteral: CGWindowListOption.excludeDesktopElements, CGWindowListOption.optionOnScreenOnly, CGWindowListOption.optionOnScreenAboveWindow)
let windowList = CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo(options, kCGNullWindowID) as NSArray? as? [[String: AnyObject]]

for entry  in windowList!
{ if let  bounds = entry[kCGWindowBounds as String] as? [String: Int],
     let owner = entry[kCGWindowOwnerName as String] as? String,
     let pid = entry[kCGWindowOwnerPID as String] as? Int32,
     let windowNumber = entry[kCGWindowNumber as String] as? Int32
  {  print("\(owner)  (\(pid)-\(windowNumber))")
     .....
```

the active windows are detected.

For some processes (e.g. notes), I get entries with the same pid but a different windowNumber.
What I want, is to move a window with a given pid and windowNumber.

I tried with this snippet:

```
let appRef = AXUIElementCreateApplication(pid); 
var value: AnyObject?
let result = AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue(appRef, kAXWindowsAttribute as CFString, &value)

if let windowList = value as? [AXUIElement]
{ ...
```

It returns a list of the windows of a process.
I want to move one of these windows with a given windowNumber (from the snippet above)

How do I find that window?

Comment: What criteria are you using to pick the relevant window from the `CGWindowList`? Couldn't you apply those criteria to the Accessibility-provided windows, instead, to pick one of those windows directly (not based on its window number)?

Comment: I have a workaround using the window title and position to detect the desired window. Works OK, but I think the Windows-ID would be more precise. I can post the workaround, if someone needs it.

Comment: How do you know the window ID?

Comment: @mica please, post how did you get WindowNumber

Comment: @Andrew:
I get the windowNumber as written above "let windowNumber = entry[kCGWindowNumber as String] as? Int32", but the solution doesn't work anymore, because I have problems getting the windowName in Catalina.

Comment: @mica if you will find way to get window name/title for getting windowNumber... please, ping me. Thanks

Comment: @Andrew In Mojave this worked for me, to get the Windowtitel.  

let windowList = CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo(options, kCGNullWindowID) as NSArray? as? [[String: AnyObject]]       
    for entry  in windowList!
    { let name = (entry[kCGWindowName as String] != nil) ? entry[kCGWindowName as String] as! String : ""

As written before, that fails in Catalina, because I do not get the permission for Screen-Reading